# Owl Carousel conflict with Masonry. Absolute positioning and overflow stuff

Tags: jquery, css, masonry

[Demo link](http://empanda.in/Blog/index2.html) ( Resize the window to ~ 768px width )

So apparently having an owl carousel slider inside a masonry item causes it to go crazy. As you can see in the link when you resize the browser. I think i found what the problem is though i don't know how to solve it. If you analyze the owl carousel a bit you'll see there's a div that has an overflow:hidden attribute which is key if you only want one slider item showing. Here's the kicker. That attribute, overflow: hidden, does NOT work when ANY of it's parents are absolutely positioned. Literally, even if it is nested in 15 elements, if the body is absolutely positioned the obvious conflict will happen.
Any ideas?

Thanks :)

Comment: Just a half-way solution: `.bp-holder{max-width: 100%;}` will fix the width problem. But won't fix the height/top position problem of the masonry.

Comment: Yes, did that myself, wouldn't even call it a solution, but thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to your problem.

```
            onResize: function(){
                setTimeout(function(){
                    var msnry = Masonry.data( '#imagesarea' );
                    msnry.layout();
                },200);
            }
```

Hope it helps ;)